# Signalr Return Model Object

Tags: json, return, signalr

The story is that, I have ROOM Model class. I want to return json with using Signalr. Is it possible ? If it is, how can i use it ?

PS: And I know that I dont return room objet to clients.

```
public List<RoomModel> GetRooms()
        {
            GameUser user = _gameService.GetUserByClientId(Context.ConnectionId);

        var room = _gameService.GetAllowedRooms(user).Select(r => new RoomModel
        {
            Name = r.Name,
            Count = 0,
            Private = r.Private,
            Closed = r.Closed,
        }).ToList();

        return room;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SignalR will automatically serialize your objects when you are sending them over to client. (I assume your client is javascript.)

As you can see in [this example](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr#baseapp) They are sending `ShapeModel` complex object to be processed in javascript. The serialization is all automated.

If your method from your example is a hub method, I suggest you end it differently. Instead of returning value, you would probably call a client event. So:

```
public class RoomHub : Hub {
    public void GetRooms() {
        List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
        rooms.Add( new Room{ Name = "Room1", Count = 12, Closed = true, Private = false});
        rooms.Add( new Room{ Name = "Room2", Count = 20, Closed = false, Private = true});

        // sending a list of room objects
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).roomInfo(rooms);
    }
}

// Room class (your complex object)
public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public bool Private { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
}
```

See details about calling from hub methods [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromhub).

Then javascript client:

```
var roomHub = $.connection.roomHub;

roomHub.client.roomInfo = function (rooms) {
    // the parameter rooms is a serialized List<Room>
    // which here will be an array of room objects.
    console.log(rooms);
    // You can read the room properties as well
    for (i=0; i<rooms.length; ++i) {
        console.log(rooms[i].Name);
        console.log(rooms[i].Count);
    }  
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("You are connected");
    roomHub.server.getRooms();
});
```

On my browser console:

[image]

Comment: Thats a very good example thank you for your labor.I edit my code like this. By the way, my client  side is android.  I am using Android Studio. One more silly question, Do you know how can i receive this json on android side?

Comment: I am not very good with that, I would probably go by this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
Can I ask how do you connect to SignalR events with Android. Do you have a tutorial or something similar?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/JabbR/Android this project to see how they can. If you have concerns feel free to ask .